# F# function to find all rotations of a list

Tags: list, recursion, f#, rotation

I have some F# code here for a recursive function that rotates a list to the left by `n` places. I am very new to F# and I'm looking for a way to modify this code to output not just one rotation by `n` positions, but all possible rotations.

For example, say I have the list:

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

I want to call rotate on this list such that the output is:

```
[ [1; 2; 3; 4]; [2; 3; 4; 1]; [3; 4; 1; 2]; [4; 1; 2; 3] ]
```

The code I have that does a left shift by n is:

```
let rec rotate xs k = 
    match xs, k with
        |[], _ -> []
        |xs, 0 -> xs
        |x::xs, k when k > 0 -> rotate(xs @ [x])(k-1)
        |xs, k -> rotate xs (List.length xs + k)
```

I'm not sure how to edit this to do the steps listed above. Any help or resources would be appreciated. I should add that I really want to function to be recursive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted to do this specific question using recursion and matchings, I managed to figure it out and this is what I came up with:

```
let rotate xs =
    let n = List.length xs
    let rec rotation xs n = 
        match xs, n with
        |[], _ -> []
        |xs, 0 -> xs
        |x::xs, n -> rotation (xs @ [x]) (n-1)

    let rec rotateList xs n = //we are compiling a list of different rotations
        match xs, n with
        |xs, 0 -> [] 
        |xs, n -> (rotation xs ((List.length xs)-n))::rotateList xs (n-1)
    rotateList xs n
```

I also specifically wanted only one input parameter, namely the list

Answer (score 8):

If I understand the question correctly, you can also write the function using the built-in `List.permute` function:

```
let rotate xs =
    let length = xs |> List.length
    let perm n = xs |> List.permute (fun index -> (index + n) % length) 
    [1 .. length] |> List.rev |> List.map perm
```

Example output (slightly formatted for improved readability):

```
> [1 .. 4] |> rotate;;
val it : int list list =
  [[1; 2; 3; 4];
   [2; 3; 4; 1];
   [3; 4; 1; 2];
   [4; 1; 2; 3]]
```

Comment: I really like this solution, thank you, the only issue i have is that I was looking for a recursive function in particular, but this certainly helps my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I would start off with making an infinite cyclic sequence off your original list. And then use `List.init` to get all the rotations.

```
let rotations list = 
    let rec cyclic sequence = seq {
        yield! sequence
        yield! cyclic sequence }
    let cyclic = cyclic list
    let length = List.length list
    List.init length (fun i -> cyclic |> Seq.skip i |> Seq.take length |> List.ofSeq)
```

the important thing is, that the sequence is lazy and therefore *can* be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `rotate` function you already wrote:

```
let rotations xs = List.init (List.length xs) (rotate xs)
```

By the way, you can shorten your `rotate` function to this:

```
let rec rotate xs k = 
    match xs, k with
        |[], _ -> []
        |xs, 0 -> xs
        |x::xs, k -> rotate (xs @ [x]) (k-1)
```

Patterns are matched top-down, so the guard `when k > 0` is not necessary. The last line of your original solution would never match, so I removed it.

Comment: Tail recursive, to boot!

Comment: BTW, better to reverse the order of parameters, so the list is the end parameter, for partial applications.
Also, if you match instead of `k` on `k % List.length xs`, and then, on the final clause of the match you do `rotate (xs @ [x]) ((k % List.length xs) - 1)` you can spare your machine a lot of redundant work...